# IDL Compiler does not recognize valuetype

Tags: java, idl

I'm using IDL to compile java classes.  When I tried to compile, it said that it doesn't recognize valuetype. Here is the compiling command, answer and relevant code:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\idlj.exe" -fall StockMarket.idl

Expected one of `typedef'`struct' `union'`enum' `const'`exception' `readonly'`attribute' `oneway'`float' `double'`long' `short'`unsigned' `char'`wchar' `boolean'`octet' `any'`string' `wstring'`' `::'`void' `ValueBase'; encountered`valuetype'.
                valuetype StockInfo {

module StockMarket {

```
exception UnknownSymbol {
    string symbol;
};

typedef string StockSymbol;

typedef sequence<StockSymbol> StockSymbolList;

interface StockServer {
    float getStockValue(in StockSymbol symbol) raises (UnknownSymbol);

    StockSymbolList getStockSymbols();

    valuetype StockInfo {
        public StockSymbol name;
        public float value;

        string toString();
    };

    sequence<StockInfo> getStockInfo();
};
```

};

Comment: Post the interface you are compiling.

Comment: I fail to see how the entire interface is necessary, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the definition of valuetypes has to be outside interfaces. Beats me as to why.